# Bash : problem with spaces and metacharacters like *. Seems impossible

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard, spaces

Here is my problem : i have a list of names, 1 per line, that can match or not some files on system.
I want to use metacharacters to match files on system.

If I have a list of two names : "a b c" and "re*", and on my system 3 files : reinc recsa reini

I'd like to write some code that will deal with 2 arguments "a b c" and "re*", and get me the list of files **one per line**.
What i tried is wrong, as a result i succeded having

```
a
b
c
reinc
recsa
reini
```

or

```
a b c
reinc recsa reini
```

But it seems impossible to get

```
a b c
reinc
recsa
reini
```

Do you have an idea ?

example with tries i made:

```
$ ls
list  recsa  reinc  reini
$ cat list
a b c
re*
$ cat list | while read name; do echo $name; done
a b c
recsa reinc reini
$ cat list | while read name; do for file in $name; do echo "$file"; done; done
a
b
c
recsa
reinc
reini
$
```

Comment: Having a hard time understand your input and output. You have six files on your system I guess, "a b c reinc recsa reini". What if they were named something else? What general task are you trying to perform?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want to write a bash script? What are "two names"? Would that be the arguments to that script? How do the two arguments relate to the files? Should a filename be printed if either of the two arguments are a prefix of the file names, or is it only the second argument? Are you interested in prefixing, at all, or is there a different logic?

Comment: Hello,
I added an example on post

Comment: So you have two lines, each of which is a list of arguments. You want the first line to be echoed verbatim, and the second line to be shell-expanded, with each result on a new line.

Will there ever be more than two lines in the file? Will the second line ever include more than one pattern? Will the first line ever contain metacharacters, or only literal strings?

Comment: the task would take a long time to describe so I reduced the question only to what is problematic for me.
To simplify i'm doing that because i will pass the result to the STDIN of tar command over ssh.

i'd like to expand metacharacters like ? * [], and deal with names with spaces. Files may exist or not on the system, if there is no file, having re* as a result is fine

Comment: "a b c" is not a list, it's 1 file named "a b c" (whether the file exists or not)
Yes on the file named list, there will be more than two lines, it can contains thousands, mixing filenames with spaces, and names with some metacharacters to expand on the system. 
I don't take care of the case where there are spaces and metacharacters at the same time (but that would a bonus)

Comment: *ls -1 $(sed 's,[[:space:]],[[:space:]],g' list)*

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to apply wildcard expansion ([filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion)) to each argument, but not [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting). Bash doesn't have a way to do one without the other: a variable substitution or a command substitution outside of double quotes (or other double-quote-like contexts) performs both, and there's no construct to perform only one. But both can be configured to be no-ops.

To effectively disable word splitting, set [`IFS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#index-IFS) to an empty string.

```
IFS=
while read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' $line
done <list
unset IFS
```

`unset IFS` effectively restores the default state. The default state is that `IFS` is set to space-tab-newline, but an unset `IFS` has the same effect on word splitting. In bash, you can keep the behavior local by doing whatever you need in a function and declaring `IFS` to be local in this function:

```
act_on_list () {
  local IFS=
  while read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' $line
  done <list
}
act_on_list
```

And if you wanted the opposite (do word splitting without filename expansion), you could disable filename expansion with `set -f`. Or you could use `read`, which also does word splitting, but you have to know how many words there are in advance.

Apart from the use of `local`, my answer applies to all non-antique sh variants, not just bash. Zsh has better ways but the standard way also works in (k)sh emulation mode.

Comment: Good idea setting `IFS=`. You could cope without the loop using `IFS=$'\n'; printf %s\\n $(< list)`. It needs a bit more memory, but that shouldn't be a problem. Bash's built-in `printf` isn't suspectible to `ARG_MAX` anyway.

Comment: Thank you! i will try it. I didn't knew that IFS affects word splitting too. 
You described my problem so well in a few good words!
And indeed i was using buit-in command echo and stdin/stdout to deal with arg_max limitations, so this solution with printf seems very nice.

I didn't think I could just turn off bash functions, I think I still have a lot to learn and I should read the entire manual to be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Use `compgen -G` to expand wildcards/globs like `*` and `?`. `compgen`'s output is one match per line. If there are no matches (for instance `compgen -G nonexistent_file`) then there is no output. If I understood you right, then you want to print `nonexistent_file` in that case. You can do so by checking `compgen`'s exist status.

```
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
  compgen -G "$pattern" || printf %s\\n "$pattern"
done < list
```

Comment: thank you. interesting! I will try this in detail too